# Default option for select not working with boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Could someone please help explain why the first and last select do not show the default value?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['myApp']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-init="options=[{id: false, label: 'False'}, {id: true, label: 'True'}]"></div>

<select ng-init="myVar=false" ng-model="myVar" >
  <option ng-value="false">False</option>
  <option ng-value="true">True</option>
</select>

<select ng-init="myVar2=false" ng-model="myVar2" ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in options">
</select>

<select ng-init="myVar3=false" ng-model="myVar3" ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in options track by option.id">
</select>
```

Comment: Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together. ref : https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/select#-select-as-and-track-by-

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase from the [`ngOptions` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) page:

> In both examples, the `track by` expression is applied successfully to each `option` in the `options` array. **Because the selected option has been set programmatically in the controller, the `track by` expression is also applied to the `ngModel` value.** When the `ngModel` value is `options[0]` and the `track by` expression evaluates to `options[0].id` there is no issue. When the `ngModel` value is `options[0].label` and the `track by` expression evaluates to `options[0].label.id` (which is undefined). As a result, the model value is not matched against any `<option>` and the `<select>` appears as having no selected value.

Comment: OK so as I'm selecting the option.id instead of just the option I shouldn't use "track by" as it would try and apply the "track by" to the ngModel value which is a boolean.

How about the first example though?